# How can I show the soft keyboard in a webview with a USB HID device attached when a button is clicked and an input is focused?

Tags: android

I have a USB barcode scanner which is plugged into the device with USB OTG. Because this is picked up as a keyboard HID device, the soft keyboard is disabled when inputs are focused.

I currently have a method which triggers the keyboard from JavaScript.

```
class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void InvokeKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(findViewById(R.id.webView), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }
}

webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "Android");
```

I'm basically wanting it to open the keyboard on the following action inside the webview.

```
const button = document.querySelector('.fire-keyboard');
button.addEventListener('click', () => Android.InvokeKeyboard());
```

It works when called from the webview manually but I want to be able to click a button which triggers it, and clicking the button loses the input box focus.

Just to add, I don't want the keyboard to show when focusing an input box, only to show when a button is clicked to trigger it. By default it shows on focus.

Comment: My suggestion is: Try set Focus on `inputbox` in javascript code after the click on button like after this line `button.addEventListener('click', () => Android.InvokeKeyboard());` use `document.your_form.input_box_name.focus();`

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan Doesn't work with a USB device attached.

Comment: I made a sample according to your scenario. Its working on my side. I am using `Nexus 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it right now but you could simply use the javascriptinterface to call this :

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

This SHOULD open the dialog with the current keyboards (input device). Since the bluetooth scanner replace the current keyboard, I am not sure you can display the softkeyboard.

With the same method, the user will switch back to the scanner if needed.

I will try it when I 'll be back home, in 6 or 7hours from now but fell free to try yourself ;)

Comment: This opens the input method picker, not the keyboard.

Comment: Like I said... I don't think this is possible, I had the same problem with a bluetooth barcode scanner and this was the only solution I found. Changing the current keyboard from the scanner to the virtual and then, change again to the scanner. So made this change as easy as possible for the user

Comment: Ah okay, that's a shame. I would've thought there would be a more seamless solution but I guess this would be last-resort.

Comment: When I had this problem, I was in a hurry so after a couple days of nothing, I use this solution.
It might depends on the API, the type of input device (not sure since the scanner I had was seen as a keyboard), the device (stock android or not). I will try with a bluetooth keyboard on Marshmallow (stock) tonight if I have a minute.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out I just needed to have this hardware toggle on.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually meet my requirements. I don't want the keyboard to show when an input is focused, only when clicking a button to trigger it.

Answer (score 6):

May be it is due to device you are using. I made a sample according to your scenario and successfully run it on `Nexus5` device which I am using.

Just use `document.getElementById("mytextfield").focus();` in JS code which did the trick.

**Sample html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<form name="myform">
<input type="text" id="mytextfield">
</form>

<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onClick="executeAndroidCode()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeAndroidCode() {
        Android.execAndroid();
        document.getElementById("mytextfield").focus(); //this line did the trick after click on button
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Save this file in asset named `index.html`

**JavaScriptInterface**

```
public class WebAppInterface 
    {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void execAndroid() {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(findViewById(R.id.webView1), 
                    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
    }
```

**onCreate Code**

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Its working fine on my side I am using `Nexus5`. Although cursor won't showed up in screenshot but it is blinking when I run the app.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a USB keyboard attached?

Comment: Your method doesn't work, no idea why you're being up voted.

Comment: He is upvoted because he writes a corrrect solution, not for every case but this is still a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this 

inputBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
      if(hasFocus) {
         getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        ((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(passwordInput, 0);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: The inputbox is in the webview, how would I bind this listener to it?